# How to constrain the text overflowing within a container?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, overflow, responsive

I'm working on a free-code-camp project and when I try to shrink this site the text 
overflows from the container which `width` is set to *"auto"*. The text is overflowing from the bottom and I have no idea why.

I have tried `height: auto`, `height: 100%`, etc., but nothing works.

Markup:

```
<section id="product-info">
    <img class="background-image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/50G4sHcs/water- 
     2208931.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="product-info-wrapper">
      <h1 class="product-info-title">Why our bottles?</h1>
      <p class="product-description">We offer bottled water cared for from 
      end to end with the idea of nothing ever becoming "waste". Our Better 
      Bottle and label are made from plants, non toxic and compostable. We 
      also offer collection for the bottles we sell, taking responsibility
        for our product post-sale and making sure that every bottle returned, 
       ends up in the correct facility, not the environment. We have been 
       developing our plant-based cap as currently, only plastic options are 
       available. The way we see it, if we
        are using plastic, it should be made from naturally renewable 
       materials and hold the ability to disappear after its useful life </p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
#product-info {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  object-fit: cover;

  max-height: 600px;
  filter: blur(1px) grayscale(70%);
}

.product-info-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /*   background: white;   */
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.product-info-title,
.product-description {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.product-info-title {
  font-family: "Kalam", cursive;
  /*   text-decoration: underline #271F30; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.product-description {
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 1.8;
  /*   height: 150px; */
  /*   padding: 10px 20px 25px ; */
}
```

I want the text to be responsive when I resize the window and I don't want to hide it, I just want it to shrink responsively.

Could you please advise me?

Comment: It's actually responsive : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKVNMN, maybe you just think it's hidden because your text is white on a white background ?

Comment: @BernardPagoaga I mean it's overflowing from the bottom of my background image container what can i do to stop it?

Comment: Then you need your background image to be bigger, so you need to remove some css from your .background-image. I updated the codepen.

Comment: Is that an option? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oKXxBr

Comment: @MaximLensky it messed up the image no an option in my case

Comment: @BernardPagoaga i want the text to be responsive relative to the container why i shink the viewport i want the text to be inside is that possible?

Comment: I'm a little bit corrected, look, so fit? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oKXxBr

Comment: @MaximLensky it works but it does go out of the container at 200px view width

Comment: further only media requests can be corrected and one css will not write for all solutions

Comment: The most adequate is not to use the img tag but to use the image as a background

Comment: now look and understand the advantage of the background image

Answer (score 0):

Add word-wrap: break-word to your CSS

For text responsiveness you can use vw units https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: word-wrap only works on the side right? not on the height?

Comment: If you have a fixed height and the text has an higuer height ot will overflow, remove your max-height:600px and it will work fine

Comment: is there any way to make the text responsive like when i shrink it shrinks as well within the container

Comment: You can use vw units, 1vw unit is 1% of the viewport width, so if you reduce the viewport width the text will adapt it font-size as this: font-size:3vw

Comment: I updated my answer, if it solves your problem please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Just dynamically adjust the font size to the available screen width.
Do your custom calculation as the default:

```
.product-description {
  font-size: calc(10px + (100vw / 200));
}
```

Then, set a maximum width with a media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .product-description {
    font-size:16px;
  }
}
```

The example above has a minimum font-size of 10px, increased by 1 for each available 200px screen width. For instance: screen width: 600px => font-size 13px

Still, you need to handle long text with care. You may reach a point, where a "read more" button/link is unavoidable.

PS: `object-fit` is not supported on IE. If you rely on that browser, rework your css to use:

`background-image: url"(myImage.jpg"); background-size: cover;`

Comment: Thanks but i still don't know how calc works, ill have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
  word-break: all;
}
```

you can use any selector you want :)
I hope it helps.